# Insert into table with "where" clause in the mapping

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to setup a mapping for a table with a composite key, but in which I'm only interested in the values with a fixed value in one of the key columns. Example:

| first | second | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 42 |
| 100 | 2 | 42 |

The goal is to have only First and Value properties in `Entity` class.

I tried mapping the table with a `where` clause:

```xml
<class name="Entity" table="table" where="second = 1">
  <id name="First" column="first" />

  <property name="Value" column="value" />
</class>
```

This configuration works fine for fetching and updating, but it crashes when I try to insert a new value with "cannot insert NULL into SECOND". I was hoping that NHibernate will parse the `where` clause and add "1" to all `insert` SQLs.

Is there a way to set a static value for a column to be added to generated `insert` statements?

UPD:
I managed to make `inserts` work with `composite-id` mapped to a quasi-readonly property, but this feels like a very dirty solution:

```xml
<class name="Entity" table="table" where="second = 1">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="First" column="first" />
    <key-property name="Second" column="second" />
  </composite-id>

  <property name="Value" column="value" />
</class>
```

C#:

```cs
public class Entity
{
    public int First { get; set; }

    public int Second { get { return 1; } set { } }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility of properties only present in the entity model. Because the Id is composite in the db it has to be mapped as such to be unique. Using FluentNHibernate to demonstrate the mapping.

```
public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .Property(x => x.First)
            .Property(x => this.Second).Access.Using<StaticValueAccessor>();
    }

    public long Second { get; set; }
}

class StaticValueAccessor : IPropertyAccessor, IGetter, ISetter
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, object> _staticValues = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { nameof(MyClass) + "." + nameof(MyClass.Second), 1 }
    };

    public bool CanAccessThroughReflectionOptimizer => false;

    public Type ReturnType { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

    public MethodInfo Method => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public object Get(object target)
    {
        return _staticValues[target.GetType().Name + "." + PropertyName];
    }

    public object GetForInsert(object owner, IDictionary mergeMap, ISessionImplementor session) => Get(owner);
    public IGetter GetGetter(Type theClass, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        ReturnType = _staticValues[theClass + "." + propertyName].GetType();
        return this;
    }

    public ISetter GetSetter(Type theClass, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        return this;
    }

    public void Set(object target, object value) { }
}
```

and query

```
session.Get<MyClass>(new MyClass { First = 123 });
```

Alternativly you could create a class for the id First and use the accessor to add an invisible property there.

Comment: I guess it should be `{ nameof(MyClass) + "." + nameof(MyClass.Second), 1 }` in the dictionary initializer. But somehow this looks even uglier than the solution I stuck with. Maybe this problem is not as trivial as I imagined.

Comment: @patart fixed. My solution looks like a lot of code but it doesn't pollute the model. It is a trade off. looking at the example you might also want to use a hierarchy and use second as discriminator.